# How to convert MS Word 2007 file into JPG file?

Tags: windows-xp, conversion, microsoft-word-2007, jpeg

How do I convert an MS Word 2007 file into a JPG file?

I need a method that will work off-line for Windows XP, preferably that does not require installing software.

Comment: @Sathya The portable part might make it less of a duplicate, but you're probably right.

Comment: Please don't use JPG for this. JPG is designed for photograph-like images, with every pixel a slightly different tone from the one next to it. A word document is usually 90% pure black and pure white. If you must convert to a bitmap image, use PNG.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is using [PDF Creator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) or something similar to it. It's free, it's offline and it's available for Windows XP. The only problem is that it's not portable, from what I know.

However, there's a second way, but it's a bit longer. You can save the documents as a PDF (Word 2007 has that option). Then, use [PDF-Xchange](http://www.docu-track.com/home/prod_user/PDF-XChange_Tools/pdfx_viewer) to save the PDF as an image.

Comment: MS Word 2007 has "Save As PDF" tool download.  If you have this, then you don't need any 3rd party software/

Comment: @kamleshrao You need third party software to save as **jpg**, which is what the OP wants. PDF Creator can save documents directly as jpg, that's why I recommended it. As for PDF-Xchange, it's useful if you have a PDF and want to save it as jpg.