# How to convert a Word 2007 document to an image file?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, conversion, microsoft-word-2007

Someone asked me to find a way to convert Word documents to image files, so he can create a photo email in Outlook (as opposed to attaching the images to the email).

I suggested saving the documents as PDF (using a plugin like [PrimoPDF](http://www.primopdf.com) or [Zotero](http://www.zotero.org/support/word_processor_integration) and then saving those as images, but he does not have Acrobat Writer, so it does not give him the option to save as an image file. I've also tried [All to Image](http://www.word-pdf-convert.com/all_to_image_jpg_jpeg_bmp_tiff_png_converter.htm), but it's not good, and I'd prefer a free solution.

Is there a way to convert Word documents directly to image files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a word document to an image (free)](http://superuser.com/questions/103533/converting-a-word-document-to-an-image-free) and [How to convert MS word 2007 file into JPG file?](http://superuser.com/questions/145911/how-to-convert-ms-word-2007-file-into-jpg-file)

Comment: @Indrek       thanks for edit, I did considered searching before writing a question but could not find, i would be ok, if someone with god points merges it, I myself do not like populating good site like this with duplicates.

Comment: With all answers appreciated and not having any plugin available or listed I will recommend him using  [Virtual Image Printer driver](http://code-industry.net/get.imageprinterpro.php) .Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found [this software](http://sourceforge.net/projects/imageprinter/): ImagePrinter

The basic idea is to use a virtual printer driver not to print to PDF but to image. That's the best idea I've got.

I haven't tried the software, but the approach should be the right one.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you are only interested in a single page image (as one really long image of multiple pages seems unusable to a potential recipient?), why not just use the Windows 7 snipping tool to create an image of that page?
[image]

Then you can paste that directly into Outlook. (or any other image editor for touchup first).

Comment: Thanks for response, Saw this online while searching as well, people seem complaining about the image quality. Isn't it something like print screen.

Comment: Yes, both print screen and the windows snipping tool do a pixel for pixel capture of the screen and place that image in the clipboard. The difference is print screen is the entire screen, snipping is a subsection of the screen. If someone is getting distortion, they are either scaling it after the paste or saving the capture in a less than optimum format.

Answer (score 1):

Print screen + Paint will do the job. Free and simple. Do the following:

1. Use the <kbd>Print screen</kbd> button (located next to <kbd>F12</kbd>)
2. Open Paint (press the <kbd>Win</kbd> key, type `paint`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste your screenshot
4. Edit the image as you see fit, then save the file as JPEG or PNG

Comment: A bit more detail would help make this a more complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

For screen capture, I use [PicPick](http://www.picpick.org) - has the ability to scroll the application Window without the scrollbars showing and in Word you just get the page without having to crop the app window away.